# How to separate column from a variable in python

Tags: python, pandas

I used this pivot function to count the number of elements in Outlet Identifer column.

```
Outlet_Count = combi.pivot_table(index=['Outlet_Identifier'], aggfunc='size')
print(Outlet_Count)
Outlet_Identifier
OUT010     925
OUT013    1553
OUT017    1543
OUT018    1546
OUT019     880
OUT027    1559
OUT035    1550
OUT045    1548
OUT046    1550
OUT049    1550
```

This is the output. I want the number of elements in different column names, how Can I do that?

Expected Output

```
Outlet_Identifier   Outlet_Count
    OUT010           925
    OUT013           1553
    OUT017           1543
    OUT018           1546
    OUT019           880
    OUT027           1559
    OUT035           1550
    OUT045           1548
    OUT046           1550
    OUT049           1550
```

I am not able to change the column name in the Outlet_Identifier. How can I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for, it would help if you include your expected output. Are you just looking for `Outlet_Count.T`?

Comment: Use `df = combin['Outlet_Identifier'].value_counts().rename_axis('Outlet_Identifie').reset_index(name='Outlet_Count')`

Comment: Or `combi.pivot_table(index=['Outlet_Identifier'], aggfunc='size').rename_axis('Outlet_Identifie').reset_index(name='Outlet_Count')`